# Sound card not detected after headphone unplugged

Tags: soundcard

This is some kind of frustrating. I am using Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS for a long time now. I am noticing this behavior since few months. Every time I plugged headphone and unplugged it then my laptop stops playing the sound. Even after I unplugged the headphone it still shows as if I have still plugged it in. I tried different solution found online. Like restarting pulseaudio, reloadng alsa, disabling auto-mute using alsamixer, etc etc. Can anyone help to get rid of this situation?

Comment: I think this worked `alsactl restore`

Comment: You can answer your own question to help other users who face the same issue and after a few days, you can mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following command and it worked.

```
alsactl restore
```